# Idiomatic to find the first element in a collection that matches a given sub-type in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am teaching myself Scala, Akka, and Play by developing a model of an order book.  I need to find the first element in a collection (specifically a priority queue) of various types of `Ask` orders that matches a certain type of `Ask` order (specifically a `LimitOrderAsk`)

The solution that I have come up with is the following:

```
bestLimitOrderAsk = askBook find {
  case ask: LimitOrderAsk => true
  case _ => false
}
```

I am new to scala and I an not sure that this is the idiomatic Scala way to solve this problem. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

```
 askBook.collectFirst{case ask: LimitOrderAsk => ask}
```

or:

```
 askBook.find(_.isInstanceOf[LimitOrderAsk])
```

If you just need to know, if there is some element (with appropriate type) - add `.nonEmpty` at the end of expression:

```
 askBook.collectFirst{case ask: LimitOrderAsk => ask}.nonEmpty
 askBook.exists(_.isInstanceOf[LimitOrderAsk])
```

Examples:

```
scala> List(5, null, "aaa", "bbb").find(_.isInstanceOf[String])
res30: Option[Any] = Some(aaa)

scala> List(5, null, "aaa", "bbb").collectFirst{case a: String => a}
res31: Option[String] = Some(aaa)
```

Boolean result:

```
scala> List(5, null, "aaa").find(_.isInstanceOf[String]).nonEmpty
res32: Boolean = true

scala> List(5, null).find(_.isInstanceOf[String]).nonEmpty
res33: Boolean = false
```

Comment: Hadn't realized there was a `collectFirst` method! Cool. I think I will go with the `_.isInstanceOf` option.

Comment: Rather than `.find(...).nonEmpty`, it would be better to use `.exists(...)` for the boolean case.